# Replace expression with subsection using regex?

Tags: regex, phpstorm

My IDE PHPstorm allows you to do search and replace using regex, one of the things I find myself often doing is switching the order or action, aka, in function a I will set a value on items from list a using list b as the values.

but then in function b I want to invert it.
so I want to set a value on items from list b using list a as the values.

A proper example is this:

```
var $clipDetailsGame        = $('#clipDetailsGame');
var $clipDetailsTitle       = $('#clipDetailsTitle');
var $clipDetailsByline      = $('#clipDetailsByline');
var $clipDetailsTeamOne     = $('#clipDetailsTeamOne');
var $clipDetailsTeamTwo     = $('#clipDetailsTeamTwo');
var $clipDetailsReferee     = $('#clipDetailsReferee');
var $clipDetailsDescription = $('#clipDetailsDescription');
var $clipDetailsCompetition = $('#clipDetailsCompetition');

function a(clip){
    clip.data('gameId'       , $clipDetailsGame.val());
    clip.data('title'        , $clipDetailsTitle.val());
    clip.data('byline'       , $clipDetailsByline.val());
    clip.data('team1'        , $clipDetailsTeamOne.val());
    clip.data('team2'        , $clipDetailsTeamTwo.val());
    clip.data('refereeId'    , $clipDetailsReferee.val());
    clip.data('description'  , $clipDetailsDescription.val());
    clip.data('competitionId', $clipDetailsCompetition.val()); 
}

function b (clip){
    $clipDetailsGame       .val(clip.data('gameId'));
    $clipDetailsTitle      .val(clip.data('title'));
    $clipDetailsByline     .val(clip.data('byline'));
    $clipDetailsTeamOne    .val(clip.data('team1'));
    $clipDetailsTeamTwo    .val(clip.data('team2'));
    $clipDetailsReferee    .val(clip.data('refereeId'));
    $clipDetailsDescription.val(clip.data('description'));
    $clipDetailsCompetition.val(clip.data('competitionId')); 
}
```

Excluding the formatting (It's just there to make my point clearer), what kind of regex could I use to do the replacement for me?

Comment: This code isn't too DRY. If that was the case, you wouldn't need this kind of search and replace.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to replace (to), or maybe it's just me ...

Comment: @mzedeler how would you mop it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Basic regex -- nothing fancy or complex at all**

Search for: `(clip\.data\('[a-zA-Z0-9]+')\s*, (\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.val\()(\)\);)`
Replace with: `\$2\$1\$3`

The only PhpStorm-related thing here is replacement string format -- you have to "escape" $ to have it work (i.e. it has to be `\$2` to use 2nd back-trace instead of just `$2` or `\2` (as used in other engines)).

This will transform this:

```
clip.data('gameId'       , $clipDetailsGame.val());
clip.data('title'        , $clipDetailsTitle.val());
clip.data('byline'       , $clipDetailsByline.val());
clip.data('team1'        , $clipDetailsTeamOne.val());
clip.data('team2'        , $clipDetailsTeamTwo.val());
clip.data('refereeId'    , $clipDetailsReferee.val());
clip.data('description'  , $clipDetailsDescription.val());
clip.data('competitionId', $clipDetailsCompetition.val());
```

into this:

```
$clipDetailsGame.val(clip.data('gameId'));
$clipDetailsTitle.val(clip.data('title'));
$clipDetailsByline.val(clip.data('byline'));
$clipDetailsTeamOne.val(clip.data('team1'));
$clipDetailsTeamTwo.val(clip.data('team2'));
$clipDetailsReferee.val(clip.data('refereeId'));
$clipDetailsDescription.val(clip.data('description'));
$clipDetailsCompetition.val(clip.data('competitionId'));
```

**Useful link:** http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html

Answer (score 2):

Mopping up (not quite the answer to this question, but another way of organizing the code to make search and replace unnecessary):

```
var $details = {};
var fields = [
    'Game', 'Title', 'Byline', 'TeamOne', 'TeamTwo', 'Referee', 'Description',
    'Competition'
];
for(field in fields) {
    $details[field] = $('#clipDetails' + field);
}

function a(clip) {
    for(field in fields) {
        clip.data(field, $details[fields].val());
    }
}

function b(clip) {
    for(field in fields) {
        $details[field].val(clip.data(field));
    }
}
```

Yes, I know that there are tiny naming inconsistencies that means that this isn't working out of the box, such as `Game` versus `gameId`. This is an excellent occasion to clean that up too :). If you still want to keep the title case for the ids (such as `#clipDetailsGame` in stead of `#clipDetailsgame`), keep it in title case in the `fields` array and use `toLowerCase` where you need lower case.

By the way, there is an interesting read on what makes DRY a good thing here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103233/why-is-dry-important